# hierarchical actors in libgdx. howto design

Tags: libgdx, onclicklistener

I have an actor (main), which has itself a list of actors (childs).
In the draw() method of the main actor I loop through the list of the child actors and I call the child-actor's draw method, which workd fine.

in my childs actor I have added an InputListener for touch events.
When adding that child seperatly to the stage, the event is fired. -> ok.

But when I add the main actor to the stage, the events of the child actors are not fired. (Because they are not known to the stage I think)

How to design this hirarchical situation with my actors, so the events of my childs are fired ?

Do I need to add all childs to the stage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `Group` class. It does exactly what you want to achieve, so either use it or  inherit from it. If both is not possible, look how it is implemented there. :-)

Comment: perfect. Thanks.